# How to handle form in react when inputs are in child components

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

i've a question about react and forms.

I've a InfluencerForm which has 3 components, each one has multiple inputs, selects forms etc and the InfluencerForm has the  and the input submit.

How can i get data from child components to handle the form submit in the parent? I'm using materialui library if it matters.

Is in the example code where you can understand, BasicInfo has about 10 inputs to be handled

```
        <Header />
          <form>
            <BasicInfo className={classes.basicInfo} />
            <Bio className={classes.bio}  />
            <div className={classes.actions}>
              <Button
                type="submit"
                color="primary"
                variant="contained"
              >
            Adicionar
              </Button>
            </div>
          </form>
      </Container>
```

Comment: You have to pass data from child to parent, so you will need to pass some handler as child property. Or for a cleaner way, use state management with techniques like redux.

Answer (score 0):

You can create function/handlers for each of you child components in your parent component, then pass those functions as props to the children.

Comment: But that way, parent component is in charge of know each element of the childs, i'm looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: You could consider using the context api to manage the state of your form. It's a bit cleaner but requires some set up